# Passing variables that contain HTML through the t() function - ! placeholder has been removed

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 8, it appears that using the ! (exclamation mark) placeholder with the t() function has been removed.

I have a variable that contains HTML:

```
<span class="fullname_wrapper"><span class="first_name">John</span> <span class="last_name">Hancock</span> <span class="account_name_wrapper">(@JohnH)</span></span>
```

I want to keep this HTML, as it will be styled specifically wherever it appears on the site.

In Drupal 7, I was able to do this:

```
t('Your name is !name', array('!name' => $name));
```

In which $name contains the HTML shown above. However, in Drupal 8, this doesn't work since the exclamation mark pass-through placeholder has been removed.

I tried this:

```
t('Your name is :name', array(':name' => $name));
```

But the HTML is still escaped.

The @ mark also escapes the HTML.

Does anyone know how HTML can be passed through the t() function in D8?

UPDATE:

According to No Sssweat's comment, it seems that my the ! mark does seem to work in t(). So here is my actual code:

```
drupal_set_message(
  $this->t(
    "@amount has been transferred to !account",
    array(
      '@amount' => '¥' . $form_state->getValue('amount'),
      '!account' => $this->accountService->formatAccountName($account)
    )
  )
);
```

And I get this error stack:

```
User error: Invalid placeholder (!account) in string: @amount has been transferred to !account in Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat() (line 235 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Render/FormattableMarkup.php).

Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat('@amount has been transferred to !user', Array) (Line: 204)
Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup->render() (Line: 15)
Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup->__toString() (Line: 451)
drupal_set_message(Object) (Line: 128)
```

The user error is what made me think the ! mark is not allowed, but I must have misdiagnosed it. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: In D8, testing with Devel Execude PHP block `$test = "<b>test</b>";
drupal_set_message(t('Something !var just happened.', array('!var' => $test)), 'warning'); ` I get the warning message, the word `test` gets bolded and not escaped. Therefore, using `!` seems to work fine in D8.

Comment: **[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQNd.jpg)**

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the original post with my actual code, and the error message I'm seeing.

Comment: try using `'!account' => '<b>test</b>'` for testing purposes. See if you still get that error. Cause perhaps `$this->accountService->formatAccountName($account)` is not a valid code. Also, note on my [testing message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQNd.jpg), I do not use `$this->t(`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and also used t() instead of $this->t(), neither worked, and the same error is still there.

Comment: Putting **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEpC3.jpg)** doesn't work?

Comment: both t() and $this->t() result in the same error.

Comment: `"both t() and $this->t() result in the same error."` **with** `'!account' => '<b>test</b>'` **?**

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Did you flush the cache when testing?

Comment: Yes, I always do.

Comment: It is bad practice to insert HTML code into the translation system. Why are you trying to achieve it?

Comment: This isn't inserting HTML into the translation system - the string is "@amount has been transferred to @account" - there is no HTML in there.

Comment: You are adding HTML in the arguments array.

Comment: Exactly. That means it's not part of the translation system, it's a variable that is swapped into the translation - after the string has been translated.

Comment: If you really think it's a problem, I'm open to reasoning behind it - please provide a link that explains that this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It appears that any arguments passed to t() function [are escaped](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/function/FormattableMarkup%3A%3AplaceholderEscape/8.2.x) unless they implement *MarkupInterface*. So that you need to represent the name as an object.

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

$formatted_name = new FormattableMarkup(
  '<span class="fullname-wrapper">
    <span class="first-name">@first_name</span>
    <span class="last-name">@second_name</span>
    <span class="account-name-wrapper">(@user_name)</span>
   </span>',
  [
    '@first_name' => 'John',
    '@second_name' => 'Hancock',
    '@user_name' => '@JohnH',
  ]
);

drupal_set_message(t('Your name is @name', ['@name' => $formatted_name]));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. It worked perfectly.

Comment: I think it's bad practice to use the t function like that.

Comment: No, it's exactly how the t() function is supposed to be used (I've been using Drupal since D5).

Comment: @Eyal Why do you think it's bad practice? It is being used to translate `'@amount has been transferred to @account'` which is a normal string with placeholders. You don't use `t()` like in `$amount . t(' has been transferred to ') . $account`. That is bad practice.

Comment: SQL injection, It's the reason the ! placeholder was dropped in D8

Comment: The reason was Twig auto escape.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2575819.
But even in Drupal 7 !placehloder could not be used for SQL injection. If the data comes from untrusted source XSS is much more real danger here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the user error you are seeing means the placeholder you are using is not recognized from `t()`. [`FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/function/FormattableMarkup%3A%3AplaceholderFormat/8.2.x), the method that does the job behind the scene, recognizes just 3 placeholder-types: *@variable*, *%variable*, and *:variable*. If the placeholder starts with a different character, it executes the following code, which causes the behavior you are seeing.

```
  default:
    // We do not trigger an error for placeholder that start with an
    // alphabetic character.
    // @todo https://www.drupal.org/node/2807743 Change to an exception
    //   and always throw regardless of the first character.
    if (!ctype_alpha($key[0])) {
      // We trigger an error as we may want to introduce new placeholders
      // in the future without breaking backward compatibility.
      trigger_error('Invalid placeholder (' . $key . ') in string: ' . $string, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    elseif (strpos($string, $key) !== FALSE) {
      trigger_error('Invalid placeholder (' . $key . ') in string: ' . $string, E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    // No replacement possible therefore we can discard the argument.
    unset($args[$key]);
    break;
```

The description for *@variable* says that the value of the variable could be:

- A string, passed through [\Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::escape()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8.2.x)
- A MarkupInterface object whose string value will not be sanitized

In your case, I would just use the following code.

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

drupal_set_message(
  $this->t(
    "@amount has been transferred to @account",
    [
      '@amount' => '¥' . $form_state->getValue('amount'),
      '@account' => new FormattableMarkup($this->accountService->formatAccountName($account), [])
    ]
  )
);
```